# Searching multiple values from one column that match a single value from another column (same table)

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following columns:
id, ref, ref_id, user_id

So far, my query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `log` WHERE `ref` = 'purchased' AND `ref_id` in (117714,117709,139171,117710,134387,117712,118270,117715,124721,139170,117708,127060,131446,131447,117718)
```

This query works, but what I need to do is only return a result if there is a `user_id` that matches each `ref_id`.

To possibly word it another way, I need to find if there is a `user_id` that purchased each of the `ref_id` values.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the group_concat function in MySQL, something like:

```
select user_id, group_concat(ref_id) from log group by user_id
```

This will give you a list of comma-separated values of ref_ids for each user_id. The tricky bit is how to compare that with the set you want. The simplest and most hacky way (if you are only going to run this query manually every now and then) is to tack a bunch of "contains" comparisons. Something like:

```
select * from (
  select user_id, group_concat(ref_id) as refs from log group by user_id
) a
where refs like '%117714%'
and refs like '%117709%'
... etc
```

You should read up on the documentation for group_concat to see if you can get the grouped values to be ordered alphabetically, in which case you can order your values and do something like:

```
where refs = '111,112,113,114' --numbers in alphabetical order
```

Hope that helps!